# How to convert extracted text from the pdf to json format in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm parsing pdf files and extracting the text from the pdf using python package. I want to convert the extracted data to JSON format. Following are my program and extracted text.

This is how my extracted text looks like.

This is my program for extracting text from PDF.

[image: program]

Comment: Give an idea about the format in which the text is to be stored in the json file?

Comment: And if your text has multiple unique fields then you'd have to extract them one by one.

Comment: I want the parsed data to be in this format{"shan jose": {
    
    "details": {
        "email": "Sshanjosemattathil@gmail.com",”shanjose.mscis3@iiitmk.ac.in”,
        "phone": +917034424559,
        
    },
    "OBJECTIVE": { 
        "Seeking a challenging job in IT industry where I can utilize my 
         total knowledge for the enlargement of company and can gain 
         further development"
 },
    "EXPERIENCE: {
        "UST Global": "I have done an internship at UST Global from Feb 06,                 2017 and completed by June 20, 2017",

        
    }
}}

Comment: Sorry pal, you need to hardcode it afterall. Just manually separate them and feed into a dict. Then dump into a .json file.